# How to group steps in one FlowStep and re-run all of the steps after failed?

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use Spring Batch to handle a bunch of precheck, validation and actions together.

If the precheck or validation fails, then I want to re-run all the pre-checks and validations regardless they previously succeeded or failed; but if an action fails, I want to start from the failed action only.

I want to group the validation or precheck in a step such as FlowStep, but it seems that the Spring retry does not support this.

Does anybody know a solution? thanks in advance!

Comment: for example, FlowStep1 = (pre checker1, pre checker 2), FlowStep2 = (valation1, validation2), TaskletStep1  = action1, TaskletStep2 = action2.  Then, if pre checker 2 failed, when retry the job, I want to pre checker1 and pre checker 2 all re-run; but if action 1 failed, then when retry the job, only start from action1. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group two steps in a `FlowStep` as follows:

```
@Bean
public Flow preCheckAndValidationFlow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("flow")
            .start(preCheckStep())
            .next(validationStep())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step preCheckAndValidationStep(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    FlowStep flowStep = new FlowStep();
    flowStep.setFlow(preCheckAndValidationFlow());
    flowStep.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return flowStep;
}
```

If you want the `preCheckStep` to re-run (even if it was successful the first time) when the validation step fails, then you need to set the `allowStartIfComplete` flag on the `preCheckStep`.

IMO, it would be much more simpler for you to create a single step that contains both the prechecks and validation logic.